# Date and Time seperation using R script

Tags: dataset, rstudio, data-science, rscript

I am unable to separate the date and time using the POSIX package in R. *This is the sample data for separating the date and time in the two separate columns*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as.POSIXct function in R.

Below are the examples to get date & time from date string.

date <- as.POSIXct(strptime(date_string, '%d/%m/%Y'))

time <- as.POSIXct(strptime(date_string, '%H/%M/%S'))